# Prove the following inequality given that $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers.

Tags: inequality

> Prove that if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive real  numbers, then
>
> $$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a} \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \right)$$

I assumed this could be solved through $\mathrm{AM} \geq \mathrm{HM}$ inequality, but I didn't get any insight into it.

Any other approach would also be really useful!

Comment: Please type the problem in you question using mathjax and not links to pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$ for any $x,y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Muirhead's inequality if you multiply everything by $2abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$

then it becomes :
$6[(3,1,1)]+18[(2,2,1)] \le 6[(3,2,0)]+6[(3,1,1)]+12[(2,2,1)] $

$\iff [(2,2,1)] \le [(3,2,0)]$ which is true by Muirhead